# Calculate the total duration of multiple audio files played in sequence / Swift 3, 4

Tags: ios, swift

For example, there are 40 audio files (A1, A2, ..., A40), of which different numbers are called up via an `AVAudioPlayer` and played one after the other. For example, the first 5 (A1, A2, ..., A5).

```
var speechPlayer = AVAudioPlayer ()
var currentPlayingItems: [String] = []

fileprivate func prepareAudioItemsToPlay () {
var result: [String] = []

    if (introSwitch.isOn) {    
    result.append ( "Intro")
    }

result += audioFileNamesForCurrentLessonType

currentPlayingItems = result.flatMap ({Bundle.main.path (forResource: $ 0, ofType: "m4a")})
currentPlayingItemNumber = 0

fileprivate var audioFileNamesForCurrentLessonType: [String] {
    guard let type = selectedLessonType else {return []}
    switch type {

    case .lesson1:
    if (statusSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    return ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"]
    }
    else if (statusSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    return ["A1", "A6", "A3, "A7", "A8", "A9","A10"] 
    }
...
}
```

How do I get the total running time of all audio files played in a selected Lesson / Status ? For example: Lesson1, first (exercise) Status:
Intro, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 (135 sec, s. below)

Let's simply assume that the duration of the audio files (in sec) are the following:
A1 = 1, A2 = 2, A3 = 3, ..., A40 = 40, Intro = 120 and these are given in a list (array, tuple, dictionary?).

Do I need an array, tuple or dictionary and how do I get the values (sec) ​​from this list (`Array`, `Tuple`,...) for Lesson(i) / status(j) to add them together, calculate the duration and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let durations:[String:Int] = ["A1": 1, "A2": 2, "A3": 3, "Intro": 120]
let fileNames:[String] = ["A1", "A3"]
let totalDuration = durations.filter{ fileNames.contains($0.key) }.values.reduce(0, +)
```

for nonunique values:

```
let totalDuration = fileNames.compactMap{ durations[$0] }.reduce(0, +)
```

Use AVURLAsset to get each audio file duration.

Comment: Excellent, but some items may appear multiple times and will be counted only once:

let fileNames: [String] = ["A1", "A3", "A3", "A4"]

How can I achieve that these items are also counted multiple times when calculating the duration.

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error:
Value of type '[String]' has no member 'compactMap'

Comment: try flatMap, compactMap was added recently.